# OS X app to swap all windows from one display to another

Tags: osx, multi-monitor

I have a Mac Book Pro with two external Thunderbolt displays. I use one as the main display and the other as secondary. Every now and then I want to switch between the two of them. Is there an app that will take all the windows from the main one and move it to the secondary and vice-versa?

If this app doesn't exist, I might consider making it: http://goo.gl/forms/fky3i9xzGA